# Joomla 2.5 database synch plugin

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla, virtuemart

I'm learning programming from a week and a bit, and seems I stuck on basics.I want to write a plugin for joomla, that will trigger every user edit any data in his profile and it will select that data and update it to second table (It have to sync. Joomla and VirtueMart user data). Hope your eyes wont bleed when you see my code, but as I said - I'm just learning, every criticism and tips are welcome.

```
<?php
defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;
class plgUserUserDataSync extends JPlugin
{

    public function __construct(&$subject, $params )
    {
        parent::__construct( $subject, $params );
    }
    protected function _getUser($user, $options = array())
    {
        $instance = JUser::getInstance();
        if ($id = intval(JUserHelper::getUserId($user['username'])))  {
            $instance->load($id);
            return $instance;
        }
        function onUserAfterSave($user){
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = $db ->getQuery(true);
            $data = array('c.name, c.street, c.postal_code, c.city');
            $query->select($db->quoteName($data));
            $query->from($db->quoteName('#__XXX_company as c, #__XXX_company_user_map as m'));
            $query->where($db->quoteName('m.company_short = c.short and m.user_id=' . (int) $user->id));
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $results = $db->loadObjectList();
            if ($db->getErrorNum()) {
                $this->_subject->setError($db->getErrorMsg());
                return false;
            }
            $query = $db ->getQuery(true);
            $fields = array(
            $db->quoteName('name'),
            $db->quoteName('address_1'),
            $db->quoteName('zip'),
            $db->quoteName('city')
            );
            $values = $data;
            $query->insert($db->quoteName('#__virtuemart_userinfos'))
            ->columns($db->quoteName($fields))
            ->values(implode(',', $values));
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $db->query();
        }
    }
}
```

After Edit:

```
<?php
defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;

class plgUserUserDataSync extends JPlugin
{

public function __construct(&$subject, $params )
{   
    parent::__construct( $subject, $params );
}
protected function _getUser($user, $options = array())
{
    $instance = JUser::getInstance();
    if ($id = intval(JUserHelper::getUserId($user['username'])))  {
        $instance->load($id);
        return $instance;
}
    function onUserAfterSave($user){
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db ->getQuery(true);
    $data = array('c.name, c.street, c.postal_code, c.city');
    $query->select($db->quoteName($data));
    $query->from($db->quoteName('#__XXX_company as c, #__XXX_company_user_map as m'));
    $query->where($db->quoteName('m.company_short = c.short and m.user_id=' . (int) $user->id));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();
        if ($db->getErrorNum()) {
            $this->_subject->setError($db->getErrorMsg());
            return false;
        }
    submitData();
    }

    function submitData(){
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db ->getQuery(true);
    $fields = array('name, address_1, zip, city');
    $query->insert($db->quoteName('#__virtuemart_userinfos'))
          ->columns($db->quoteName($fields))
          ->values(implode(',', $results));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->query();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's current happening with your code? Also, when you define your database table names, what is the `XXX` after `#__`? If this is your table prefix, then remove it. That is what `#__` is used for. You're also quoting the columns twice, so remove the `$db->quoteName()` from inside the `$fields` array. You also have a spelling mistake, change this `$db->setQueery` to this `$db->setQuery`. You should not be putting a select **and** insert query together as this could cause conflicts. Put each action in a separate function.

Comment: @Lodder - XXX stands for part of table name I dont want to show to public, but it's not prefix. I updated my code trying to follow your advices, but it's still not working, and I'm running out of ideas where I'm doing misstakes.